# Trying to install Ubuntu 12.04, log to a black screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, nvidia, windows-8

I have the same problem as [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162087#162087) and the solutions there did not help me fix it. I want to dual boot this to my Windows 8.1. I disabled fast and secure boot, when I restart my computer it does not detect the LiveDVD, I have to shift+restart for it to detect it, and when it does it shows me a black screen with three options (Try, Install, Check for Problems) and not the purple one where I can press F6 and solve my woes. When I press 'e' to edit the boot parameters, there are only three lines of parameters, the second one ending in quiet splash --. I tried adding nomodeset after the word splash then pressing F10 to boot with those configurations, and that did not work either. It's probably relevant information that I have two graphics cards: an integrated Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600, and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770M.

What should I do?

--EDIT:

Ok, so, I managed to install it, by deactivating UEFI and going through lengths and pains. Then I used a boot repair disk to make it possible to boot into Ubuntu, and all. Ok, so now I boot, and I get these options:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)
- Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
- Windows Boot UEFI loader
- EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
- System setup

Choosing the 3rd or 4th option loads Windows normally, choosing the 5th causes me to load a weird power recovery thing, choosing the 1st loads a blank purple screen, and the 2nd loads a blank black screen. System setup loads the BIOS thing.

I expect, then, that I need to get the drivers to run ubuntu. What to do?

(Possibly relevant: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9784753/ the pastebin my boot recovery disk created.)

Comment: What one of the three options did you use? See this alot with Nvidia. When starts boot and shows keyboard icon on bottom, press key. Then do install, not try. This always worked for me. So basically what you posted, but skip the adding options. Just go right to install. Once installed you will need to probably need to use proprietary drivers. Just go to dash and search drivers once installed.

Comment: Like I said, that screen does not appear. No purple screen with keyboard icon on bottom, just the black one with three options.

Comment: Right, but was one of those options was install, right. Did you try that instead of try. This is what I did when used Nvidia. When you restart you may get black screen, but then rather than choose first Ubuntu in grub use second. Then select failsafe graphics. This will get you into ubuntu so you can install proprietary Nvidia driver

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't work either. Still black screen, with or without 'nomodeset' set.

Comment: Now I deactivated the UEFI and after much suffering and crying I managed to install it. Now I need to find a way to boot it because I couldn't install the boot loader. I'm trying this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: Are you saying that grub does not come up, it just boots into Windows? For me, on my hp laptop I can ether press f9 when first turn on and select ubuntu, then ubuntu again when Grub loads. Or I found if I enable network boot in my bios, when computer restarts I press F12, it quickly realizes that there is no network boot and loads grub.All said and done, about 3 seconds. So this is my preferred way (with UEFI disable).

Comment: I can select ubuntu now, but it doesn't load. It stays on a purple/black blank screen, nothing graphical on it.

Comment: Try the second listing. It's like ubuntu recovery or repair or something like that. In there you should find option for failsafe graphics, run that, go through prompt. Last option is to boot. Once in, update Nvidia driver restart. You may also want to look into Nvidia ppa for latest drivers

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Going to the second listing shows me a black blank screen, like I mentioned in the edit of the post. I can't get it to run ubuntu for me to get the Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to do it.

I formatted the partitions I'd dedicated to ubuntu, then activated Secure Boot again, at which point my computer started detecting the LiveUSB I'd started using even with UEFI activated. I was still getting a black screen, but the fact that it flashed me a view of the desktop before going black suggested that all was not lost. I removed quiet splash and added nomodeset to the configurations, et voilà, I could install it.

After finishing the installation, I restarted my computer, went to the UEFI menu to change the boot priority, and successfully booted into ubuntu, though no grub menu with the list of operational systems showed up.

Still, victory! It works.

Answer (score 0):

Go back into Ubuntu Recovery Mode. Look for an option *"Drop to root shell prompt"*  and do that.  By default it read only so we need to fix that

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now that we're mounted rw and in a root shell add ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa (assuming your card is in there - [Source](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) just scroll till you get to Nvidia drivers. If you find card, add ppa)

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

And then

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

finally

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-verson#
```

Then restart

Also you can remove if needed by using

```
 sudo apt-get remove nvidia-version#
```

<strike>Ubuntu 12.04 does not support UEFI</strike>

My bad, it does

**Edit 2**

Because also get black screen in recovery, as suggested in comments - if you can get a livecd to boot using try ubuntu (think you said it worked after you disable UEFI) you can then mount your root partition and then add the ppa

Comment: I can't go into Ubuntu Recovery Mode, like I said. It just shows me a blank black screen when I choose that option.

Comment: I'm sorry I was no help. I'm bailing out since I don't have anything on me to try to duplicate the issue. Only other suggestion at this point is try a fresh install.

Comment: "I should have read more carefully that your using 12.04, could have saved some time cause UEFI not supported in that version" Yeah, that version does in fact support UEFI, it's the first one that does.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that and removed

Comment: If only you could try ubuntu and get it to load. Then you could mount the root partition and then follow my answer.

Comment: To boot from livecd I'll have to deactivate UEFI again, I presume. I think I tried to do that already, but not sure. I'll try it again, thanks.